# Python Read range of lines from txt on a server and write them to local file

Tags: python

I have a log file on a remote server and I want to write to a file the lines i have chosen to write.

The thing is that print(linex) below is OK and I see all lines in CMD console.
But it is writing only the 1st line to the file.

What am I missing here...?

```
def GetEndLastLine ():
    last_line = sum(1 for line in open('//10.10.10.10/d$/log/server.log'))
    print(last_line)
        with open('//10.10.10.10/d$/log/server.log') as f:
        for linex in itertools.islice(f, first_line, last_line):
            break
        x = open(r"LogFile.txt", "w")
                print(linex)
                x.write("LOGS START HERE****\n\n"+ output +"")
                os.system("start notepad++.exe LogFile.txt")
```

Comment: Your indentation is off, so it's hard to say anything but you seem to `break` from the loop after the first line.

Comment: Why the unnecessary indentation?

Comment: Sorry. I`m new at Python. Will the indentation fix the issue? even without the Break it is not working as epxected. it keeps openning the new file for writing for each line printed instead whole lines in same file open

Comment: Managed to get it all into the file but now the result is One long line with \n, Tried the splitlines() function but no luck. any suggestions how to put that line in order like in original file?

Comment: The output text is written to file like that : ['\Bla Bla Bla\n Bla Bla Bla\n'] - in original file it looks OK line by line. The reading is done like that :  lines = text_file.readlines()
    lines = lines[first_line:last_line].  Any ideas how to solve it so it will look like original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should write the entire content of `server.log` to your local `LogFile.txt`.

```py
with open('//10.10.10.10/d$/log/server.log') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
with open("LogFile.txt", "w") as f:
   f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thanks! how should I insert 2 parameters i fetch as lines range? The script suggested is writing all lines. i need range of lines. I already got the range line numbers

Comment: Edit your question with your input and your desidered output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help- opening a new thread for the other issue which is different